# SQLite basics in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

So I have a VBA macro which I put together quite recently, and does an adequate job, if painfully slow. However, I have been told to port it to VB.net (various reasons, a main one being that the Software team don't want to be stuck supporting VBA macros if I move on).
A key part of the process in VBA was running a couple of lookups on another sheet in the same workbook.
The table in question is ~10,000 values, and looks something like:

1. Location | Ref-Code | Type
2. Aberdare | ABDARE   | ST

I can put the columns in any order, but what I need to do is check that a value is found in Ref-Code, and if it is return Location and Type.

So, first sub-question: is SQLite the right tool for doing this? Would something else be more sensible for looking up values in a persistent, rarely-altered 10,000ish row table from VB.net?
If SQLite is the right tool, are there any good tutorials to take me through how to connect to and query an SQLite database in VB.Net? I haven't been able to find one yet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use an xml file to store the lookups. There are [loads of easy ways to parse xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) files in VB and this way you don't have to learn how to connect to SQLlite at all.

The xml file can also be maintained by someone who doesn't know anything about databases.

Comment: Thank you! I am sure I will need to learn SQLite (or SQL) at some point, but that seems like a good way to stay out of the quagmire for now.